# how to build cakeHP 3 custom data source?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How do we migrate custom data source which is not related to database.

It is related to update records from external service create, update, delete.

Comment: The cakephp team is building an elastic-search datasource that's utilizing the new ORM - you should be able to find some inspiration there https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3 - Where is custom datasource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411494/cakephp-3-where-is-custom-datasource)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497797/how-to-use-a-restful-api-as-orm-in-cakephp-3/29499598